# Sqlite3 - How to import NULL values from csv

Tags: mysql, csv, sqlite

I have dumped a mysql table as CSV. In this CSV file, the NULL values are written as `\N`
Now I want to import this data into sqlite database, but I am unable to tell sqlite that `\N` are null values. It is treating it as a string and that column value is stored as "\N" instead of NULL.

Can anyone guide in how to use `.nullvalue` dot command from sqlite. I am unable to set `\N` as nullvalue.

```
sqlite> .show
nullvalue: ""
sqlite> .nullvalue \N
sqlite> .show
nullvalue: "N"
sqlite> .nullvalue '\N'
sqlite> .show
nullvalue: "\\N"
sqlite> .nullvalue "\N"
sqlite> .show
nullvalue: "N"
sqlite> .nullvalue \\N
sqlite> .show
nullvalue: "\\N"
sqlite> .nullvalue '\'N
Usage: .nullvalue STRING
sqlite> .nullvalue '\\'N
Usage: .nullvalue STRING
sqlite> .nullvalue \\N
sqlite> .show
nullvalue: "\\N"
sqlite>
```

This is the output after every value of `nullvalue`

```
sqlite> .import /tmp/mysqlDump.csv employee
sqlite> select count(*) from employee where updatedon='\N';
94143
sqlite> select count(*) from employee where updatedon is null;
0
```

**How can I tell sqlite to treat `\N` as NULL value?** I cannot use empty string as NULL value as my data contains empty strings.

Comment: Related question; same thing but for a mysql load: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data . Just in case someone is debating which database to use and this is an important consideration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get missing values recorded as NULL when importing from csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370007/how-can-i-get-missing-values-recorded-as-null-when-importing-from-csv)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

CSV files contain only text values. It is not possible to import NULL values from a CSV file.

To convert the `\N` values into NULLs, just use UPDATE afterwards:

```
UPDATE employee SET updatedon = NULL WHERE updatedon = '\N';
```

Answer (score 3):

When sqlite is configured to check foreign key references, a method that relies on doing an update after the import is not possible, because the import would fail (the foreign key constraint would fail) and there would be no row to update.

For that, and the cases where doing an update after the import is unacceptable, you must modify the shell.c file in the amalgamation (as shown below), and compile a new sqlite(.exe) binary.

The change to be made is to bind the parameter for the field to NULL when the field is empty (with `sqlite3_bind_null`) instead of unconditionally binding it as a text field with `sqlite3_bind_text` as is currently done.

An example of making that change to sqlite version v 3.33.0 2020-08-14 is below (as a patch diff).

The example has the changes behind a new compile-time option, `SQLITE_IMPORT_NULL_IF_EMPTY`, so to enable it you'd need to define it when compiling like so:

```
cc -DSQLITE_IMPORT_NULL_IF_EMPTY <other options> shell.c sqlite3.c -o sqlite3
```

Example full compilation command with recommended options (and a few others set):

```
cc -Os -DSQLITE_IMPORT_NULL_IF_EMPTY -DSQLITE_DQS=0 -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_MEMSTATUS=0 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_WAL_SYNCHRONOUS=1 -DSQLITE_LIKE_DOESNT_MATCH_BLOBS -DSQLITE_MAX_EXPR_DEPTH=0 -DSQLITE_OMIT_DECLTYPE -DSQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED -DSQLITE_OMIT_PROGRESS_CALLBACK -DSQLITE_OMIT_SHARED_CACHE -DSQLITE_USE_ALLOCA -DSQLITE_OMIT_AUTOINIT -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEYS=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_NULL_TRIM -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RBU -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_DBSTAT_VTAB -DSQLITE_ENABLE_EXPLAIN_COMMENTS -DHAVE_USLEEP -DHAVE_READLINE shell.c sqlite3.c -lreadline -lncurses -o sqlite3
```

Patch file contents:

```
--- sqlite-amalgamation-3330000/shell.c 2020-08-14 13:42:48.000000000 +0000
+++ shell.c     2020-10-07 13:23:39.000000000 +0000
@@ -17845,7 +17845,12 @@
         ** the remaining columns.
         */
         if( p->mode==MODE_Ascii && (z==0 || z[0]==0) && i==0 ) break;
+#ifdef SQLITE_IMPORT_NULL_IF_EMPTY
+        if (z==0 || z[0]=='\0') sqlite3_bind_null(pStmt, i+1);
+        else sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, i+1, z, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
+#else
         sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, i+1, z, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
+#endif
         if( i<nCol-1 && sCtx.cTerm!=sCtx.cColSep ){
           utf8_printf(stderr, "%s:%d: expected %d columns but found %d - "
                           "filling the rest with NULL\n",
```

Comment: You could also temporarily disable the foreign key checks:
`PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;` ... import and fix your data ... `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`

Answer (score 0):

A bit beter patch:

```
+        if (p->nullValue[0] != '\0' && cli_strcmp(z, p->nullValue)==0) sqlite3_bind_null(pStmt, i+1);
+        else sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, i+1, z, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
-        sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, i+1, z, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Now, when .nullvalue is set its value is replaced to NULL while importing CSV/TSV file.