# Import unquoted empty space as NULL from CSV into SQLite using CLI

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, csv, command-line-interface

`test.csv` looks like this:

```
"Code","Member","Position","ModDate"
"AAN","Smith, John",,1/21/2020 0:00:00
"AAN","Doe, Ron",,1/21/2020 0:00:00
"AAN","Doe, Jane","C",1/21/2020 0:00:00
```

Note that 2 values in the `Position` column are missing. They're blank. There are no quotes, no `''` or `""`, just empty space between 2 commas: `,,`.

**Is it possible to import such values as `NULL` into SQLite using the `sqlite3` CLI?** So far, it'll only import them as empty strings: `''`. (Yes, I could use Python or run `UPDATE ... SET` (see later), but I'm wondering if a simple CLI command will suffice.)

Put another way, I want to run this query to get rows with missing positions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE position IS NULL
;
```

But so far I can only achieve that result with this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE position = ''
;
```

---

First I tried the default:

```sh
sqlite3 -csv test.db ".import test.csv tbl"
```

As I said, this imports null values as empty strings.

`sqlite3`'s [`-help` text](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) mentions a `-nullvalue` option:

```
-nullvalue TEXT      set text string for NULL values. Default ''
```

I assume this is for importing. I try this:

```sh
sqlite3 -csv -nullvalue ",," test.db ".import test.csv tbl"
```

No luck. And I don't know what else to try. I can't find any further explanation of the `-nullvalue` option in SQLite's docs or any examples with Google.

---

Perhaps I could just update these values after importing, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36780320/8605348):

```sh
sqlite3 -csv test.db ".import test.csv tbl"
sqlite3 test.db
sqlite> UPDATE tbl SET position = NULL WHERE position = '';
```

However, this isn't entirely satisfactory. First, I have multiple CSVs and multiple columns within each of them that I must update. This would require repetition. Is there a better way?

Comment: Doesn't it insert `NULL` when you import without any `-nullvalue` parameter? idk maybe try the CSV Lint plugin for Noptepad++ https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint and just convert the csv file to an SQL insert script, it automatically converts empty values to `NULL` though not sure if the output script is compatible with SQLite3.

Comment: You mean `sqlite3 -csv -nullvalue test.db ".import test.csv tbl"`? That doesn't seem valid. Entering this just continues the line, like the command expects to be finished.

I'd just use Python instead of a manual process in a text editor. I was wondering if it's possible with the sqlite CLI.

Comment: I have a perl script for importing CSV into sqlite that can do this among many other things. Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: @Shawn, I can do it in Python if there really is no way to do it with the sqlite3 CLI.

Comment: CSV files do not have data types, and CSV files do not have a NULL value concept, so every value SQLite imports is imported to the database with `sqlite3_bind_text`.  If you want any other behavior, you'll need to use something other than the SQLite shell.

Comment: @AnonCoward: Yes, but the CLI lets you specify which values the parser should consider NULL. Is there no way to make the `sqlite3` CLI import this specific pattern--`,,`--as NULL?

Comment: "CLI lets you specify which values the parser should consider NULL"  There is no such functionality.  `.nullvalue` lets you control what is displayed when a NULL value is displayed from a query, nothing more.

Comment: @AnonCoward: I see. If you're sure there's no way to do what I want with the CLI, write it as an answer and I'll mark yours as The Answer.